# How can I get error code when I execute an incorrect process?

Tags: java, powershell, processbuilder

I'm trying to start the powershell script through processbuilder and I'm sure there's an error there, but such commands as exitValue() and waitFor() always return 0 - OK status. Any ideas for catch erros?

P.S. I know that I can parse and view ErrorStream, but..In general, some messages in ErrorStream suit me (they do not affect the script), but there are messages (powershell exeption), like unkonown command or bad command or connections error which should let me know that there was a serious error

P.P.S. my code below:

```
Process process = null;
String path = "Path\\To\\PowershellScript.ps1"
    int isErrorProcess = 0;
    int isErrorProcess1 = 0;
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe", path);
        pb.directory(new File(path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("\\"))));
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        process = pb.start();            
        ProcessBuilder.Redirect rd = pb.redirectError();
        // Get input streams
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(),"866"));

        // Read command standard output + error
        String s;

        System.out.println("\nOutput:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        isErrorProcess = process.exitValue();
        if(isErrorProcess == 0 && isErrorProcess1 == 0){ //why always 0 even if powershell script with erros
            isErrorStatus = false;
        }
        process.destroy();
        return isErrorStatus;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        process.destroy();
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        return true;
    }
```

Many thanks

Comment: Maybe your OS forbids to execute powershell scripts? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-6

Comment: @hellow No, all commands are executed well

Comment: I'm not sure what else you expect Process.exitValue() to do. You create a process and get it to run powershell to run to which it does. So why should the exitValue be anything other than '0'?

Comment: @PengTuckKwok Because if i run the script from a command line, it is executed with an error and if i run script from jar it run without error

Comment: Can I suggest you print out your 'path' in both scenarios to see what it is actually set to?

Comment: @PengTuckKwok yes ofc, in case when i run PS1 script from java, path = "d:\Work\download.ps1"; in case when i run PS1 script from commandline i just execute the command "cmd" then navigate via CD command and execute "powershell" then "./download.ps1" commands

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the time,
try:

```
//no this
 process = pb.start(); 
//but this
 process = pb.inheritIO().start();
```

and you see the output from the console using System.out.println(s);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).